# How to import desgin of an Excel Template in Angular as Object

Tags: excel, angular, npm, xlsx, exceljs

I want to Import data from Excel, after modification i want to export the updated data.

I am able to import data from Excel file using XLSX package, but while i export the new data, all the styling is gone.

I want persist the Design/Style/Theme of the excel while exporting.

```
// For Import
  importExcel(e) {
    const bstr: string = e.target.result;
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
    const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
    return of(<AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1,  })));
  }

// for Export of File   
  exportAsExcelFile(data: any[]): void {
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }

i want to persist the design of excel template
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xlsx** is package available on **NPM** by **sheetJS**.
They provide template export only in their **pro-version**.

you can use **exceljs** instead.
this is also available over **npm**

check [How to import EXCEL file in angular using exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595103/how-to-import-excel-file-in-angular-using-exceljs) for reading a excelfile in angular using exceljs