# How to import EXCEL file in angular using exceljs

Tags: angular, exceljs

I want to read excel file using angular code.
my file is stored somewhere in my local system e.g, C:/data/test.xlsx

I have already tried loading with 
readFile() & load() methods of exceljs.

they fail to read anything, instead they give error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I found the way to read excel file from Angular code. Convert the file
>   into **ArrayBuffer** and read it using **exceljs**

1. Importing Exceljs in angular **service**/**component**

```
    import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js';
```

---

2. Modify tsconfig.app.json

```
    compilerOptions: {
       paths": {
             "exceljs": [
               "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js"
             ]
          }
     }
```

3. Open file from html code.

```
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" (change)="readExcel($event)" 
           class="upload input-common" required />
```

---

4. Using exceljs for reading file.

```
    readExcel(event) {
        const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target);
        if (target.files.length !== 1) {
          throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
        }

        /**
         * Final Solution For Importing the Excel FILE
         */

        const arryBuffer = new Response(target.files[0]).arrayBuffer();
        arryBuffer.then(function (data) {
          workbook.xlsx.load(data)
            .then(function () {

              // play with workbook and worksheet now
              console.log(workbook);
              const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
              console.log('rowCount: ', worksheet.rowCount);
              worksheet.eachRow(function (row, rowNumber) {
                console.log('Row: ' + rowNumber + ' Value: ' + row.values);
              });

            });
        });
      }
```

Also polyfill.ts must reference in this sequence ..
    `import 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js';
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';`